# Не работает proguard для тестов

Tags: android, espresso, proguard

Доброго времени суток.

Завел файлик, proguard-test-rules.pro, но у меня не получается подключить его к тестам.

Если я добавляю нужную мне строку  в основной proguard  все работает, в тестовый отбивает ошибку, из этого я сделал вывод что он у меня не подключается.
Может мне кто подсказать что с этим делать? Или есть возможность проверить подключен ли он?

```
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testProguardFile 'proguard-test-rules.pro'

        buildConfigField "long", "VERSION_DATE", System.currentTimeMillis() + "L"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        ext.betaDistributionNotifications = true
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testProguardFile 'proguard-test-rules.pro'

        buildConfigField "long", "VERSION_DATE", "0L"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
```

Comment: А с какой целью вы вкючили прогуард для debug сборки?

Comment: Так было до меня) 
Я только начал заниматься автоматизацией мобилок, так что вразумительного ответа я дать не могу

Comment: Обычно для дебажных сборок выключают прогуард, иначе он вам там все наоптимизирует и наизменяет, что отлаживать приложение станет не возможно, плюс все это значительно увеличивает время сборки. Поэтому я бы посоветовал отключить все это(оставить только для релиза)